# Azure SQL Database "Activity Monitor"

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

One of my Azure SQL Databases is experiencing very high CPU usage.  This is a test database server and is definitely not receiving any traffic so it should be very under-utilised.

[image: Azure Monitor]

Is there any way I can troubleshoot this to find where this load is coming from?

Is there some kind of Activity Monitor for SQL Database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use SQL Azure Dynamic Management Views.  Check out this article for more info to get started: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-monitoring-with-dmvs

Comment: I keep getting an error:
VIEW SERVER PERFORMANCE STATE permission was denied on object 'server', database 'master'.
Is there a way to get an Activity Monitor output on AzureSQL? I can't find anything that works.